# How to import `displayHTML` in DataBricks?

Tags: python, databricks, azure-databricks

I created a python package that relies on `IPython` to display HTML in notebooks in different environments like Jupyter or Google Collab.
While testing it with DataBricks I noticed it doesn't work at all.
Code example:

```py
from IPython import display, HTML

my_html_str = '<img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/karolzak/boxdetect/master/images/checkboxes-details.jpg"/>'
display(HTML(my_html_str))
```

The above code would work everywhere but in DataBricks. For DataBricks, I need to run `displayHTML(my_html_str)` in one of the cells to make it display my HTML.
The problem is I need to run `displayHTML` from my python package code level and when I'm doing it there it raises an error saying that `displayHTML` doesn't exist. It does run correclt only if I run `displayHTML` from one of the code cells in DB notebook.
Code for displaying HTML inside my package:

```py
if "DATABRICKS_RUNTIME_VERSION" in os.environ:
    displayHTML(html_viewer)
    return displayHTML(html)
else:
    from IPython import display, HTML
    display(HTML(html_viewer))
    return display(HTML(html))
```

With above code I get below error when trying to run in DataBricks:
[image]

The question is how should I import `displayHTML` inside my package code to make it work correctly for DB?

Answer (score 4):

Here is an alternative way to import the required packages into your block.

```
from IPython.core.display import display, HTML
display(HTML("your content"))
```

Comment: Sorry mate, but I don't think you understood my problem. IPython display doesn't work in DataBricks environment. I need to use DataBricks function `displayHTML` but it only works when invoked in a code cell directly. It doesn't work when I add it inside my package code.

Comment: This works when applied within a .py file stored in a REPO.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it is possible to import `displayHTML` in a standard way. Apparently, the function is defined inside the `PythonShell` class which is instantiated and executed in `/databricks/python_shell/scripts/PythonShellImpl.py`, providing no way to call the function from an external package such as yours.

To solve this problem, I used the `inspect` module (just like the `plotly` library when used inside databricks). Here is a code snippet that should work in your case (of course, you could make it prettier inside a class, with a dynamic attribute - see https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/blob/master/packages/python/plotly/plotly/io/_base_renderers.py line 780 for inspiration) :

```
def display_html(html: str) -> None:
    """
    Use databricks displayHTML from an external package
    
    Args:
    - html : html document to display
    """
    import inspect
    for frame in inspect.getouterframes(inspect.currentframe()):
        global_names = set(frame.frame.f_globals)
        # Use multiple functions to reduce risk of mismatch
        if all(v in global_names for v in ["displayHTML", "display", "spark"]):
            return frame.frame.f_globals["displayHTML"](html)
    raise EnvironmentError(
        "Unable to detect displayHTML function"
    )

my_html_str = '<img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/karolzak/boxdetect/master/images/checkboxes-details.jpg"/>'
display_html(my_html_str)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks @Paul Minder, this looks very promising! I'll give it a try

Answer (score 0):

In Databricks the display functions is coming from PythonShell

```
import PythonShell as pi
pi.PythonShell.display(temps)
```

This works in Databricks but this is not whitelisted for outside use.